# How does this defn method1 [{:keys [a b c] :as obj}] map method works?

Tags: clojure

I have the following Clojure code

```
(defn myFunction [{:keys [a b c] :as myAtom}]
  (let [new-a 1]
    (+ new-a a)
  (assoc myAtom :a new-a)))
```

I would like to know how :keys and :as work

Comment: Its called (key) parameter destructuring, nice overview at http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html

Comment: That is a really good article thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first line defines a function (in a var) that takes a single argument which must be a map

```
(defn myFunction [{:keys [a b c] :as myAtom}]
```

Then It creates a let statement binding the given symbols `a` `b` `c` to the values obtained by looking up each of the symbols as a keyword in that argument, and bind the name myatom to the original map

```
  (let [new-a 1]
```

Then bind `new-a` to the value 1

```
    (+ new-a a)
```

do some math and ignore the result

```
  (assoc myAtom :a new-a)))
```

This last segment uses the symbol bound to the whole map (passed as an argument) as and calls assoc to create a new map associating :a with the value in new-a. Then retrurns that as the value of the function.

This returns a new map with the value 1 for :a

```
user> (myFunction {:a 3 :b 3 :c 3})
{:a 1, :c 3, :b 3}
```